# Using libvlc to stream a video from memory?

Tags: streaming, vlc, libvlc

I am generating a video stream in real time, and I've got it as a series of bitmaps in memory.

I'd like to stream these bitmaps over the network using libvlc, but I wasn't able to find the right functions in the API (all streaming functions expect a file or other source).

I even thought of emulating a capture device, but that seemed too convoluted to be true, so I'd rather ask.

My question is, what do I now have to do with these bitmaps to be able to use libvlc to stream them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694876/how-can-i-load-a-memory-stream-into-libvlc) which appears to be solving the same issue.

Other suggestion with significantly less overhead is "emulating" a file with named pipes, i.e. FIFOs.